# BST Delete Function does not Delete Intended Node (Java)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a delete function for my BST class. I am trying to follow a few standard tutorials, and am good with everything besides my delete function. I don't get any errors, but it doesn't delete the intended node. I am recursively getting to the intended Node, returning the opposite side node if it only has one child, otherwise I am returning the smallest value from n.right.

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

```
public class BinaryTree {

    private Node root = null;

    private class Node {

        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        private int data;

        public Node(int data, Node left, Node right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public boolean add(int data) {

        root = add(root, data);
        return true;

    }

    private Node add(Node node, int data) {

        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(data, null, null);
        }

        else {
            if (data < node.data) {
                node.left = add(node.left, data);
            }
            else {
                node.right = add(node.right, data);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    // Helper function

    private Node findMin(Node node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private Node findMax(Node node) {
        while (node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;
        }
        return node;
    }

    private void inOrderTraversal(Node n) {
        if (n == null) return;

        else {
            inOrderTraversal(n.left);
            System.out.println(n.data);
            inOrderTraversal(n.right);
        }
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal() {
        inOrderTraversal(root);
    }

    private Node deleteKey(Node n, int data) {

        if (n == null) return n;

        if (data < n.data) deleteKey(n.left, data);
        else if (data > n.data) deleteKey(n.right, data);

        else {
            if (n.left == null) return n.right;
            else if (n.right == null) return n.left;

            n.data =  findMin(n.right).data;
            n.right = deleteKey(n.right, n.data);
        }
        return n;
    }

    public void deleteKey(int data) {
        root = deleteKey(root, data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinaryTree bst = new BinaryTree();

        bst.add(2);
        bst.add(8);
        bst.add(1);
        bst.add(7);
        bst.add(3);
        bst.add(11);
        bst.add(1);
        bst.add(21);
        bst.add(10);
        bst.add(12);

        bst.inOrderTraversal();

        System.out.println("----------------");

        bst.deleteKey(3);

        bst.inOrderTraversal();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from drawing your deleteKey algorithm out as a flowchart. Not a flowchart of your code as written but a flowchart of how it was supposed to work. A cursory glance makes me think your bug might be a failure under some circumstances to write the n.left or n.right references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `deleteKey` function:

```
private Node deleteKey(Node n, int data) {

    if (n == null) return n;

    if (data < n.data)
        n.left = deleteKey(n.left, data); // must reassign child here
    else if (data > n.data)
        n.right = deleteKey(n.right, data); // must reassign child here
    else {
        if (n.left == null) return n.right;
        else if (n.right == null) return n.left;

        n.data = findMin(n.right).data;
        n.right = deleteKey(n.right, n.data); // this was correct
    }
    return n;
}
```

When `data < n.data` or `data > n.data`, you aren't updating the current node's leaves. So this was *finding* the appropriate node to delete, but it wasn't rebuilding the node branches properly on the way back up from the recursion.